# How is >> called?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I've found out what the difference between `>` and `>>` is.

My question is this: 
In the context of command line code, what is `>>` called?

As in:

```
dir *.txt >> mytext.txt
```

Double chevron? Pipe to? Over-write?

Comment: The character is a Chevron, so I guess it's a double-chevron

Comment: It redirects & appends http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: @musefan _chevron_ is  a common moniker for inverted V-shaped symbol `^` _Circumflex Accent_,  codepoint `U+005E` in Unicode. Undertaken from heraldry. Cf. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chevron?s=ts

Comment: I guess specifically I should say right-chevron as opposed to left

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255262/what-is-the-name-of-the-symbols-and

Answer (score 4):

I personally call it the "Append To", but don't have any source to back that up.

Examples:

```
dir *.txt >> Output.txt   ("list text files, Appended To output.txt")
dir *.txt > Output.txt    ("list text files, Redirected to output.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

As `>` is called *Greater than* then `>>` could be **Double Greater than**

BTW,

- [*chevron*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chevron?s=ts) is rare programmer's name for inverted V-shaped symbol `^` *Circumflex Accent* (other time called [*caret*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/caret?s=t) athough caret is another symbol) and
- *chevrons* is another name for `〈 〉`– [angle brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Angle_brackets), pointy brackets, triangular brackets, diamond brackets, or tuples; (hard to type that symbols from computer keyboard).

Here's a PowerShell output from Unicode database:

```
PS D:\PShell> '^<>〈〉‸'| Get-CharInfo | Format-Table -AutoSize

Char  CodePoint         Category Description        
----  ---------         -------- -----------        
   ^  U+005E      ModifierSymbol Circumflex Accent  
   <  U+003C          MathSymbol Less-Than Sign     
   >  U+003E          MathSymbol Greater-Than Sign  
   〈 U+3008     OpenPunctuation Left Angle Bracket 
   〉 U+3009    ClosePunctuation Right Angle Bracket
   ‸  U+2038    OtherPunctuation Caret
```

Answer (score 0):

The ">>" syntax will create an output to a new file. If the file to the right of the arrows is already created, it will add whatever you're trying to add to the end of the file.

Comment: OP didn't ask what the function is, he asked what ">>" is called

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I;m new to the stack community.

Answer (score 0):

It is known as redirection .

Basically input redirection. **>>** indicates an append in the file ,whereas, **>** indicates a new file creation if you are using *redirection*  followed by a file name.

Different programming languages have different usage like in Python  **>> is Binary Right Shift** and **<<  is Binary left Shift**

In Postgresql , it is used for picking the vale as text or integer from an array element if the structure is json.

One more thing, symbolically it is known as  **chevron** and  **double-chevron**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes.  Batch files also use it for logical shifts.  From the SET command help: **<< >>               - logical shift**

Answer (score 0):

In the context of [io-redirection](/questions/tagged/io-redirection), I prefer using the term ***output redirection*** for both `>` and `>>`, because the output of a command is redirected. To distinguish between them, I specifically use:

- `>` -- ***output redirection in overwrite mode***;
- `>>` -- ***output redirection in append mode***;

For the sake of completeness, for `<` I use the term ***input redirection***. The `|` is called a ***pipe***.